# Date formatting AngularJS to display only the day and month

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am completed newbie to Angular. So I have date value for created_at. which is

```
2008-04-25 00:00:00
```

I want to get only the day similarly month in English. I have tried the following to make sample to get Year alone. But the filter not seems to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<h2>Recent Study</h2>
    <ul ng-repeat="x in names">
         <li>
            <div class="date">
            <span class="day">{{ x.created_at |  date : 'yyyy' }}</span>
            <span class="month">Jul</span>
            </div>
            <p><a href="#">{{ x.study_description }}</a></p>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: I have checked it out. I think mysql date time should be converted something. can you help with that?

Comment: Try `names[0].createdAt.replace(" ", "T")`. Anyway I think you should convert your date values properly in the server instead.

Comment: I've edited my answer below, take a look

Answer (score 9):

You need to convert the date to seconds, and use a custome filter:

```
app.filter('toSec', function($filter) {
  return function(input) {
      var result = new Date(input).getTime();
      return result || '';
  };
});
```

and use it in your HTML like this:

```
{{ '2008-04-25 00:00:00' |  toSec | date:'EEEE'}}
```

result:

```
Friday
```

Angular gives you the option to create a [Custome Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Here's a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9JIlXHAkTy8jwOEWZRon?p=preview) that achieves what you need using a custome filter.

Comment: Because none of your examples are working for me. The date needs to be formatted like this `2008-04-25T00:00:00` (note the big **T**). The idea is correct though and I would gladly upvote you if you edit your answer.

Comment: @Goodzilla the date is formatted like this in the question: (2008-04-25 00:00:00) there's no T. look at the working example, it works as the op wants. I've edit my answer

Comment: How can I use this filter to display Today is day is today and then day names for other days

Answer (score 1):

created_at's formatting isn't compatible.

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

Cited from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

for example "2008-04-25T00:00:00" would work.

Comment: Can you help me with my problem. I have tried to do this

Comment: @divakar [Have you ?](http://jsfiddle.net/m8LyqkLg/) If you're gonna ask questions, at least take the time to read the answers.

Comment: @Goodzilla I have read the answer. I am getting the date format not with T included. I need idea for convertion. I know the format is nt compatible. that's Why i need help

Answer (score 1):

I hope your getting the input as time stamp ,in your code just change the filter to get the only day

```
<h2>Recent Study</h2>
    <ul ng-repeat="x in names">
         <li>
            <div class="date">
              <!-- getting only day  -->
            <span class="day">{{ x.created_at | date:'dd '}}</span>
                <!-- getting month name and  day only -->
            <span class="month">{{ x.created_at |  date:'MMM-dd '}}</span>
            </div>
            <p><a href="#">{{ x.study_description }}</a></p>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

here   `date:'dd '` gives   Day in month, padded (01-31) and

```
date:'MMM-dd ' gives Month in year (Jan-Dec) and above day in month.
```

Comment: No am not gettting it into time stamp as i told already my format

Comment: may i know what is dynamic value of  x.created_at ?,As of now i feel it is 13 digit number .can u answer my question .

Comment: I think @Nitsan Baleli  suggestion is working,if not after creation of your dynamic date convert it to  string by using [toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tostring) function and convert it to time stamp then you can play it in angular js .Although it is not working let me know further info by create a plunker for it.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The problem is simple. We should convert the mysql date time to javascript date time then only you can format it in javascript.

so my format is:2008-04-25 00:00:00

```
  app.filter('format', function () {
          return function (item) {
               var t = item.split(/[- :]/);
           var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
           var time=d.getTime();                 
                   return time;
          };
        });
```

I have converted the mysql to javascript and then to millisecond then applied my filter its working.This may be not efficient. Its working in great manner. Hope this helps someone.

so my html:

```
 <li  ng-repeat="x in names">
                <div class="date">
                <span class="day">{{ x.created_at | format | date:'d'}}</span>
                <span class="month">{{ x.created_at | format | date:'MMM'}}</span>
                </div>
                <p><a href="#">{{ x.study_description | makeUppercase}}</a></p>
            </li>
```

Its working fine. @Nishanth answer is giving me undefined. I have upvoted it since its seems working fine for some people. The date format support vary on browser tools too.