# Date filter formatting Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to show `date` and `time` on my app in this format,

```
Date: 14 - 19 Sep
Time: 16:30 to 18:30
```

And I'm getting data from server in below format,

```
"EventDate":"2015-09-14T16:30:00Z",
"EndDate":"2015-09-14T18:30:00Z",
```

I tried angualrjs `date` filter,

and now I'm getting date in below format,

```
Sep 14, 2015 - Sep 19, 2015
```

I tried many examples from **SO** but didn't work for me,

[Date formatting AngularJS to display only the day and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845202/date-formatting-angularjs-to-display-only-the-day-and-month)

How can I display my Date in following format,

```
Event Date: 14 - 19 Sep
Event Time: 16:30 to 18:30
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Evdate = {
    "j": [{
      "EventDate": "2015-09-14T16:30:00Z",
      "EndDate": "2015-09-14T18:30:00Z"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  {{Evdate.j[0].EventDate | date}} - {{Evdate.j[0].EndDate | date}}

</div>
```

Comment: have you considered the case of 30 Jan to 4th Feb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed the format argument. Look the documentation [filter / date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.Evdate = {
        "j": [{
          "EventDate": "2015-09-14T16:30:00Z",
          "EndDate": "2015-09-14T18:30:00Z"
        }]
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 Event Date : {{Evdate.j[0].EventDate | date : 'd'}} - {{Evdate.j[0].EndDate | date : 'd MMM' }}<br />
  Event time : {{Evdate.j[0].EventDate | date : 'HH:mm' : 'UTC' }} to {{Evdate.j[0].EndDate | date : 'HH:mm' : 'UTC' }}

</div>
```

Comment: Cool!! This will help me a lot buddy!! :)

Answer (score 1):

For month. Try this.

```
{{Evdate.j[0].EventDate | date : 'd'}} - {{Evdate.j[0].EndDate | date : 'd MMM'}}
```

For time

```
{{Evdate.j[0].EventDate | date : 'HH:mm'}} - {{Evdate.j[0].EndDate | date : 'HH:mm'}}
```

Hope it helps. Notify me if it doesn't work.

Comment: By your code I got this `14 - 15 Sep 22:00 - 00:00` Time is not correct

Comment: Sorry. I'm busy so I didn't reply in time. Glad someone helped you. Just keep hackin' :)